# Different sizes of Fancybox window (iframe) for different links

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, size, fancybox

I have some links on my web page. When you click them Fancybox windows with iframe opens up, which works fine. However, I want to change the windows sizes so that it's different on the different links.

How could I accomplish what I want? Should I change in the Fancybox.js-file?

This is how my links look.

Link 1:

```
<a class='various' data-fancybox-type='iframe', href='/blog/' + blog._id.toHexString())>
```

Link 2:

```
<a class='various' data-fancybox-type='iframe', href='/image/' + image._id.toHexString())>
```

Comment: What version of fancybox are you using? because the solution o @MrD implies creating a separated script for each link you have. That would be OK if you have a couple of links but what if you have 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through Jquery's

```
$('#divid').fancybox({
            padding: 0,
            scrolling: 'yes',
            autoScale: true,
            autoDimensions: false,
            height: xxx,
            width: xxx
        });
```

Comment: I won't! One more thing you may be able to answer. I can't get the windows height bigger than 400px, even though the maxHeight is set to 800px. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Check your css one of the parent elements may be set to a height of 400px?

Comment: Actually, no. Very strange. :/ I'm using Fancybox for showing images in full scale as well, and those windows have more height than 400px.

Comment: Are the images on the same domain?

Comment: sorry to drag this up after so long, but as i have the same question i thought it more appropriate than to start a new question.

is this method still applicable for fancybox v3?

i have three href links on my page and i want/need them to behave differently. 1 link to be default (ie autosize) which it currently does. 1 link to have a set width/height and 1 link to have anothet set width/height.